# Did I lose access to the quest because I lost a game of Gwent?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Around the time you get your stuff back in Vizema, just after the talking to

> the King and Yennifer

there is a gentleman sitting the the courtyard with a yellow "!" questmarker on the mini map.

I rushed over, eager to get a new quest, and ended up in a game of Gwent which I only narrowly lost despite having far inferior cards.

The quest icon promptly disappeared and now I am wondering if I lost my chance to get a quest from this guy.

Has anyone beaten him at Gwent and received a quest or is the marker just there  to indicate that you can play Gwent with him? I would assume that this is not the case as it disappears after losing.

Comment: I beat him, and just ot a card of him. I don't think there is more to him.

Comment: do you remember which card you got?

Comment: @Nitro.de I think the reward cards are random

Comment: @Colin not always, card you recieve for quests are always the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completed that particular bit a few hours ago. If I recall, nothing happened after I'd beaten him, I'm pretty sure it was just to signify that you could play gwent against him.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Nilfgaardian_Nobleman_(Royal_Palace_at_Vizima)) he doesn't launch a new quest, but he is instrumental to the [Collect 'Em All](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Collect_%27Em_All) quest. I believe that the mark is indeed to specify you can play Gwent with him because beating him is vital to completing the Collect 'Em All quest (as well as the [Card Collector](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Collector#Card_Collector) achievement).